# Reading long sequence of digit as string

Tags: epplus

I'm using EPPlus to read a customer database.
From time to time in a text cell I'm reading as string, the customer wrote a long sequence of digit
My code read it as exponential format.

Is there a way to force the reading as string?

Here's the code snippet I'm using

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(xlsFile))) {
var myWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, 1].GetValue<string>())) 
    {
        var cell = myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, 20];
        var idDoc =  cell.GetValue<string>(),

        // do something with idDoc

        rowNum += 1;
    }
}
```

when the cell contains, let's say 1790002099190700, idDoc is "1,7900020991907E+15"

Comment: It seems that cell.Text contains the right value, whereas cell.GetValue<string>() converts the value (guessing the type) to numeric, then returns a string version.
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing make sense as excel will store the value as a `double` like any other numeric value.

It looks like you are exporting from a database to excel.  I would assume that when exported there is no formatting set in Excel in which case using the `.Text` value of the cell object simply fall back to "General" in excel.

Say you have this:

[image]

So, what you end up with is this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Cell_Digits_As_String()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058900/reading-long-sequence-of-digit-as-string

    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Cell_Digits_As_String.xlsx");

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
        var valCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];

        var valText = valCell.Text; //Applies "General" unless otherwise specified
        var valValue = valCell.Value; //As a BOXED double
        var valString = valCell.GetValue<string>(); //Falls back to ChangeType

        Console.WriteLine($"Value as text: {valText} ({valText.GetType()})");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Same as: {((double)valValue).ToString("0.#####", new CultureInfo("es-US"))}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Value as value: {valValue} ({valValue.GetType()})");
        Console.WriteLine($"       Same as: {valValue.ToString()}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Value as string: {valString} ({valString.GetType()})");
        Console.WriteLine($"        Same as: {Convert.ChangeType(valValue, typeof(double)).ToString()}");
    }
}
```

Which shows this in the out:

```
Value as text: 1790002099190700 (System.String)
      Same as: 1790002099190700
Value as value: 1.7900020991907E+15 (System.Double)
       Same as: 1.7900020991907E+15
Value as string: 1.7900020991907E+15 (System.String)
        Same as: 1.7900020991907E+15
```

So, it would seem that using `.Text` is the most convenient to get what you want.  But if you are concerned about the formatting being altered in any way or just want to be absolutely sure, just do:

```
try
{           
    ((double)valCell.Value).ToString("0.#");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle it...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the exhaustive answer! I really appreciate it!!